# PHP false negative with == on strings

Tags: php, types, type-conversion, string-comparison

There are lots of examples of false positives when using `==` to compare two strings in PHP.

For example, `'1' == '1.0'` is true.

However, are there any false negatives? Is there some string `$a` such that `$a == $a` is **false** due to type juggling?

Comment: if you want avoid some false positive use strict compare '1' === '1.0'  so you compare type and value and not only value

Comment: Or you can use `strcmp()` and `strcasecmp()` to compare string.

Comment: Is that a typo? Or are you really looking for a string that is not equal to itself? Because no, there is no situation in PHP where `$a == $a` would ever evaluate to `false`.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: I'm sorry, but a string comparison from "1.0" == "1" is not true.  If you want to compare the values of the strings, you need to convert them to numeric values before or during the test:  if (floatval('1') == floatval('1.0')) would be true, as it is comparing the correct types.  Read about type juggling:  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: PHP will still type juggle even if both inputs are already strings. `var_dump('1.0' == '1')` => `bool(true)`, but `var_dump('1.0' === '1')` => `bool(false)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, php will not provide false negatives.  php will create false positives via type juggling *as a feature* (it tries to help).

Related questions:

[php string comparison unexpected type juggling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12872756/php-string-comparison-unexpected-type-juggling)

[Type casting and Comparison with Loose Operator "=="](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6680408/type-casting-and-comparison-with-loose-operator)